# Apply common function to all data frames and return data frames with same name

Tags: r, list, plyr, lapply

I'm trying to apply a function to all similarly spelled data frames in my global environment in R.  I want to apply this function to all these data frames, but I can't figure out how to do it without me specifying 1 by 1.   I want to return the data frame to the global environment with the same spelling as it was before.

```
mtcars_test = mtcars
iris_test = iris
#....etc......could be 2 of them or 88 of them...but they will all end in "_test"

# figure out what data frames I am working with
list_of_my_dfs = lapply(ls(pattern = "*_test"), get)

#my function just multiples everything by 2
mytest_function = function(df){ df = df*2; return(df)}

helpme_return_these_dfs_to_outside_the_list=plyr::llply(list_of_my_dfs, mytest_function)
```

This is where I need help.  I want to apply my function to each data frame within the list AND then 'return' the data frame from that list to my environment.    So `mtcars_test` and all other data frames will be multiplied by 2 everywhere and returned back to global environment.

Comment: Why not keep everything in a list to begin with?

Comment: I can keep it in a list but the for purpose I'm in right now I need them extracted.  I already know how to do that and think I'm doing that right now.

Comment: The "answer" is probably `list2env`, but please don't bother with that. Just keep them in a list.

Answer (score 3):

**1) environment subscripting** Set `e` to the environment containing the data frames and then get their names and loop over them as shown:

```
BOD_test <- BOD  # not all columns of iris are numeric so use BOD instead
mtcars_test <- mtcars

e <- .GlobalEnv
nms <- ls(pattern = "_test$", envir = e)
for(nm in nms) e[[nm]] <- mytest_function(e[[nm]])
```

**1a) assign** An alternative to the last statement would be:

```
for(nm in nms) assign(nm, mytest_function( get(nm, e) ), e)
```

**2) lists** You might want, instead, to keep the data frames in a list:

```
L <- sapply(nms, get, envir = e, simplify = FALSE)
L[] <- lapply(L, mytest_function)
```

**2a) sapply** or if you do not want to overwrite `L` then:

```
sapply(L, mytest_function, simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `eapply` to iterate over an environment and then `assign` to store an object to your global environment.  The function argument to `eapply` will be an anonymous function which first gets the df from global, assigning it to a temp variable, pass it to your function and then use assign to put it back to global.

Comment: can you give me an example?  i've never heard this function mentioned before.

Comment: Read the help files!  What you want to do is advanced, read dangerous, so you really need to take the time to learn what you are doing.